# Decryption of password encrypted using PASSWORD() function of mysql

Tags: php, sql, password-encryption, password-recovery

I am using`PASSWORD()`function of SQL for encrypting passwords . Now i am searching for a way to get the password if someone forget his/her password.

```
$user = "select * from users where email='$email' and password='PASSWORD($pass)'";
```

Thanks

Comment: There is an alternate of it, by updating that password but i want a way to decrypt it also.

Comment: If I see a website where I can recover my password I consider the developer incompetent http://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs

Comment: Password should be [ecrypted on-way/hashed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). You should never be able to retrieve a user's password.

Comment: Your methods might be correct but after thinking from user's point of view, i am thinking i should drop the idea of decrypting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never store your passwords in a way that they can be decrypted. Instead just generate a new password.

Something like:

```
UPDATE users SET `password` = 'PASSWORD(someSuper.Safe123Password!)' WHERE `id` = USERID
```

Comment: ya i know this but for some reasons if don't want to update and as a developer if i am encrypting some thing i should know a way to decrypt it also.

Comment: I agree that storing passwords in a way that can be decrypted is generally bad practice, much better to just use a secure hashing algorithm, but there are some cases where you want to store data in a way that can be decrypted again (not necessarily passwords but some other data) because just changing the data there is not an option.  In that case you could use something like RSA - very secure (used by banks) but if you know the private key then it is easily decrypted - just means you have to make sure the private key is stored securely (preferably on a completely different system).

Comment: @Terwanerik I know this approach but as i have mentioned i don't want to update it.

Comment: Of course you can use RSA or any other key-based encryption, but we are talking passwords here. Most people still only use a couple of passwords for all their accounts, if one developer decides to use crappy encryption, or -heaven forbid- the developer leaks his key, all these accounts are at jeopardy. I would even recommend you to encrypt and salt your passwords, just for extra safety; no worse publicity than 'website leaks xxxx passwords via security bug'

Comment: @Terwanerik Thank you for changing my approach and know i came to know that its better to make someone's approach better rather than giving a solution to his bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

`PASSWORD()` is a hashing method and therefor it can't be decrypted to the orginal string
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html

So the answer to your question

If you want to encrypt/decrypt you can use the `AES_ENCRYPT` and `AES_DECRYPT` methods
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt
Or the `DES_ENCRYPT` and `DES_DECRYPT`

NOTE: It's not wise to store passwords that can be decrypted for security reasons, you could better set a new password. Or in your case when a user forgets his/her password you can generated a random string and use that as password in your database the generated password could be mailed to your end-user.

As noted by hd you could better use the generated string as reset token for your end-users.

Comment: It should be noted that the generated random string that is e-mailed to the user should act as a "token" for them to log in to be directed to change their password straight away, and not to be used as their actual password, especially as you'd be sending a plain-text "password" via e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

You cant recover this password in direct way, only you can use brute-force attack or using rainbow tables for this hashes.

Or if you dont want to recover it you can change it via update command from mysql.